# How to view the maximum in Decision Center Business Console of IBM ODM 8.5.1?

Tags: ilog, odm, jrules

We have a Decision Table that has 8 condition columns and 4 action coloumns.

It is kind of not so comfortable for the Business User to scroll and have a look at all the columns to look at in the Business Console, as the Business Console has Properties and Stream on the Right Hand Side of the Business Console, that is not so required.

Am not able to resize the same, even though I see a mouse pointer, that can potentically resize the console pane to drag further to the right, so that I can have a maximized view of the decision table.

Any pointers in the right direction are greatly appreciated...

Thanks a lot in Advance....

Comment: Figured out at the time of edit for the rule, it shows up in full on the business console... that was a no brainer... Thanks Guys

Answer (score 1):

You can separate your action columns within specific Decision Tables, this is one approach. So in your case you should have 04 Decision Tables, instead of just one.

This is not a problem, but a long-term solution if you plan to separate things and other question as the business evolves.

Another approach would be to use the `Otherwise` feature available in Decision Tables. With this feature you can shrink the number of combinations when the main question gives an `else` case. It helps a lot.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

For viewing purpose, you can copy paste the whole table in an excel sheet.